# Visual Studio 2015 view all comments

Tags: visual-studio-2015, comments

So, I'm working on a .Net project in VS 2015 with the idea of it serving as a tutorial/reference sheet for others at work.  With this in mind, I am commenting as a main method of communicating important points in the code.

My question is: Is there any way to view all comments across an entire project/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Documentation Generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as the best format for this. The methods in your classes should have a descriptive summary, and if totally necessary for your purposes, quote an important line. i.e.

```
/// <summary>
/// This function multiplies two integers and returns the product.
/// Important lines include "return num1 * num2;"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="num1">The first number</param>
/// <param name="num2">The second number</param>
/// <returns>The product</returns>
public int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;
}
```

And then (following instruction in link) generate your documentation for the solution.